# Define a type of local class in a class template

Tags: c++, templates

Assume class `Data` has a local class template `Element<i>`, the following code has a compilation error. Code seems simple, but what is wrong?

```
template<unsigned i, class Data>
class A
{
public:
    typedef typename Data::Element<i> ElementTy; // compilation error: token error
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `template` keyword:

```
typedef typename Data::template Element<i> ElementTy;
```

This tells the compiler that the name following is a template.